# Javascript: how can I make a function that will execute code whenever something is true?

Tags: javascript, onkeydown

I am creating my first JS library (mostly for the sake of learning), and I would love to have a simple function with two parameters, (**key** and **code**). This function would execute **code**, which would usually be something like "myFunction()", whenever the **key** key is "down" (like onkeydown). Here is an example:

```
function moveForward() {
    // some code
}
function jump(height) {
    // some code
}

// whenever the w key is down, run the function "moveForward".
ice.keyDown("w", moveForward);

// whenever the space bar is down, run the function "jump".
ice.keyDown("space", jump);
```

It's worth noting that I would also have two similar functions, ice.keyUp and ice.keyPress. These would pretty much do what you would expect, same as ice.keyDown but for onkeyup and onkeypress.

In addition, I would like to be able to have a fourth function that takes three parameters, **key**, **code**, and **mode**. this function, likely called ice.keyRemove, would remove any existing ice.keyDown/Up/Press functions that would execute **code** when **key** is down/up/pressed. To clear ALL ice.keyDown/Up/Press functions that would execute any code when **key** is pressed, you would use "all" as the parameter **code**. Another example:

```
// whenever the control key stops being pressed, run the function "myFunc".
ice.keyUp("ctrl", myFunc);

// whenever the control key is pressed (onkeypress), run the function "myOtherFunc".
ice.keyPress("ctrl", console.log("8 pressed"));

// stop running stuff when the ctrl key is down/up/pressed.
ice.keyRemove("ctrl", "all", "all");
```

I hope that all makes sense. As I mentioned before, this is mostly for the learning experience, so please don't just give me the code, but explain what may work/not work and why. I also know that there are libraries out that can do this, like [Keypress](https://dmauro.github.io/Keypress), but again I am mostly trying to learn how something like this is most efficiently done.

Comment: Don't use `()` when creating event handlers, ex: `ice.keyDown("w", moveForward);`

Comment: Thanks! I will edit that now. learned something already!

Comment: without parenthesis, you hand over just the function without calling it.

Comment: @user1655756 Okay, that makes sense. would ice.keyDown(parameters) simply add the code parameter to, say, an array of functions that are run when the key is pressed?

Comment: Do you need key combinations like in Keypress?

Comment: @AliNaciErdem Not yet, for now I think just a single key would be enough.

Comment: @user1655756 sorry, I was a little unclear about how the timer would execute the code, especially if there are more than one functions to be run with one key. Would it have an array of all the functions to be run if some key is pressed, and loop through running each one? or is there a better way?